# React website showing "Not secured" hosted through GoDaddy

Tags: reactjs, ssl, hosting, cpanel, httpurlconnection

I have created a basic ReactJs website and hosted it using GoDaddy cPanel and secured domain through "Punchsalad" site using free SSL for 90 months. Website link is: http://www.paperware.co.in/
When I visit website using **http://**, it shows not secured but when I try to visit website using **https://** it shows secured website. I have tried changing homepage url in package.json file from http to https but nothing worked.
Currently homepage set in package.json --->`"homepage": "https://paperware.co.in"`

Comment: You have both secured and unsecured versions - use https in all cases

Comment: React has nothing to do with this, consider removing it as a tag

Answer (score 1):

For redirect to https in cPanel you most used bellow code in .htaccess in cPanel:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```